# Intellisense is not showing TargetControlID in calendar control

Tags: c#-4.0, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I added AjaxControlToolKit through NuGet to my Visual Studio 2010, added a reference in my .aspx page. In the calendar control, intellisense is not showing TargetControlID attribute. 
Can you help me in this. 
thanks !

Comment: Um.  Does it show in the properties window of the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference in your project to `System.Web.Extensions`.

I just ran into this in Visual Studio 2010, with both the 2006 and the Nov 2011 AjaxControlToolKit releases. Following normal rules I added a reference to AjaxControlToolKit, added the appropriate using statement, and there was no `.TargetControlID` field. When I got frustrated and put the property in (since all posts I found on Google said it worked for them!) and hit compile I got a complaint that I was missing a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`. Added it and up came all my "missing" attributes.